# AutoHotKey - Key spamming does not work like I want it to

Tags: autohotkey

Key Spam does not work so good.

Here is the code:

```
Loop
{
If GetKeyState("z", "P")
  send w
If GetKeyState("g", "P")
  send a
If GetKeyState("j", "P")
  send d
If GetKeyState("h", "P")
  send s
}
```

but when I hold `z` or `zg` together, then the original keys `z` and `zg` come all time once or twice between the `w` or `wa` output.

What can I write that the keys `z+g+h+j` never will be seen in the text file only `w+a+s+d` if I run this script?

Comment: Why don't you just remap each key? `z::Send, w`

Comment: @MCL You should pose that as an answer for him.

Comment: @BGM I was just going to leave. If you'd like, you can do it. You have my blessing ;)

Answer (score 0):

Karoline, you are going about it the wrong way.  Autohotkey was designed to do just what you *really* want to do.

As MCL says in his comment, you need only to map your keys to a send function

Put this in your script:

```
z::send w
g::send a
j::send d
h::send s
```

Now, when you push `z` it will type `w` instead.

Keep in mind that this is global over your entire computer unless you limit it to notepad using `IfWinActive`.  The script will not exit on its own.

Answer (score 0):

but this doenst work like i want

i want that i can press g+z same time or z+j same time or g+h same time or h+j same time

and that i get then awawawawaw or asasasasasasas or wdwdwdwdwdwdwd

that when i press 2 buttons same time it switch output ever 1 char

and when i use your answer and holz z it spams wwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwwww
and if if press then z+g it only continou spaming wwwwwwwwwwwwww not wawawawawawawawaw

thans

Karoline

Comment: Karoline, please edit your question instead of putting extra lines as an answer

Comment: As pointed out by Liel, this is no answer. Please either update your question or post it as a comment to the corresponding answer. Most importantly, delete this post.

Answer (score 0):

According to your "answer", you are targeting a keyboard behaviour that's not standard. That is, using remapped keys with AHK or not, when pressing two letter keys *simultaneously*, **solely** the key pressed at last will continue firing.
Here's an example on how you can achieve an alternating behaviour instead:

```
SendMode, Input

g & z::
z & g::
    Send, aw
return

g::Send, a
+g::Send, A
z::Send, w
+z::Send, W
```

You will have to explicitely define every custom combination with an **&** modifier, which makes them [prefix keys](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#combo). This comes with an upside and with a small downside: The upside is, you can now keep pressing your combination and it will continue firing two keys in an alternating fashion; no loop or the like required. The downside: You need to reconstruct prefix hotkeys' original behaviour. In our example, that's sending a lowercase or uppercase letter.